# Inserting values from an xml node that has the same name inside the node in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to insert some data from an XML into a table but the way the XML is structured the root name is the same as a child and this causes a ghost column in the table. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

See my example below.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
           (
               Id   INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
               Var1 NVARCHAR(50),
               Var2 NVARCHAR(50)
           )

DECLARE @X XML = '<TEST SEGMENT="1">
                  <VAR1>1</VAR1>
                  <VAR2>2</VAR2>
                  <TEST SEGMENT="1">
                    <NAME>SomeName</NAME>
                    <ADDRESS>SomeAddress</ADDRESS>
                  </TEST>
                </TEST>'

INSERT INTO @A(Var1, Var2)
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value('(VAR1)[1]/text()[1]', 'bigint'))), ''),
        ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value('(VAR2)[1]/text()[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'))), '')
    FROM 
        @x.nodes('//TEST') o(x)

SELECT * FROM @A
```

The output is 2 rows of data one with null values:

[image]

Comment: By the way, you can shorten to `x.value('(VAR1/text())[1]',` also `LTRIM(RTRIM(` can become `TRIM(` in newer versions of SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was caused by the double forward slash in the FROM statement.
EX:

```sql
FROM @x.nodes('//TEST') o(x)
```

VS

```sql
FROM @x.nodes('/TEST') o(x)
```

[This is documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/path-expressions-using-abbreviated-syntax?view=sql-server-ver16)

A double slash "//" means any descendant node of the current node in the HTML tree which matches the locator.

A single slash "/" means a node that is a direct child of the current.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98715faf3af73e7d01fe15de42b8ffaa)

Comment: I do not know, if it is a good practice to ask a question, and give an answer to it, by yourself, to just point out that you had misread a syntax, or did a typo in the code.